# Comparing Time Stamp

Tags: php

So I have this method,

```
$time2 = get_the_time( __( 'F Y h:i:s A ', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID );
```

that returns a string something like this "Tuesday 21st of January 2014 05:51:00 AM"

and I have this other method that returns a timestamp "1392099616"

```
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
```

I'd like to get their difference in seconds.

I'm looking into strtotime, can anyone elaborate?

EDIT: Both Method returns string data types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your get_the_time like,

```
$time2 = get_the_time( __( 'd-m-Y H:i:s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID );
```

then,

```
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
$time1 = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time);

$date1 = new DateTime($time1);
$date2 = new DateTime($time2);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

print_r($interval);
```

You'll get the difference.

Comment: So I had this working, how am I going to use the [s] section? lets say I'll put it into a variable $seconds?

Comment: Are you want to get hours, min, seconds etc? $interval is object type so you can access it by,
$days = $interval->d;
 $months = $interval->m;
 $years = $interval->y;
 
 $hours = $interval->h;
 $mins = $interval->i;
 $seconds = $interval->s;

Answer (score 1):

```
 $time2 = get_the_time( __( 'h:i:s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID );
```

change  time2  to this and you will get the the time value and you can compare these

```
$time1 = strtotime('09:00:59');
$time2 = strtotime('09:01:00');
$gap = $time2 - $time1;
echo 'Time 1: '.date('H:i:s', $time1).'<br>';
echo 'Time 2: '.date('H:i:s', $time2).'<br>';

if($gap){
    echo date('H:i:s', $diff);
}else{
    echo '------';
}
```

Comment: It gives me something like, "05:51:00". Haven't tried comparing it though,

Comment: if you get  both the  time in same format just subtract them and you will get total time in seconds

Comment: What I did is change $time = current_time( 'mysql' ); and $time2 = get_the_time( __( 'Y m d H:i:s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ); 

They show the same format, but the problem is when I subtract them the result is 0. I think that is because they have the same string data type.

Comment: what r the two values you getting

Comment: I get this for $time = 2014-02-11 15:24:59 and $time2 = 2014 01 21 05:51:00.

Comment: change the $time to  time with strtotime()  and after that make difference

Comment: I just get a -1392131114 in diff. Could that be parsed into a date? I don't really understand the format of timestamp.